# What do I need to do in Power Automate to make this plain text?

Tags: json, power-automate

I have a Cognito form with a cascading Lookup Dropdown column. I have a flow that takes that form information and puts it into a Sharepoint list - the lookup column is coming up in Sharepoint looking like JSON. Example: N/A is coming up in Sharepoint as {"Id":"16-1513","Label":"N/A"}. 6 is coming up as {"Id":"16-1391","Label":"6"}.

I'd prefer not to have to do a looooooooong split/delete expression. I feel like someone on here will know exactly what it's doing and have a clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Parse JSON action that might help. You then use the output from a test run to generate the schema. That then allows you to select the fields.

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!